# Subtracting Datetime Objects in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am comparing timestamps and the results are not what I expect. For example, I have the following datetimes:

```
2019-03-04 08:52:00 - 2019-03-04 08:53:00 = -1 day, 23:59:00
```

I would expect the result to only be a difference of 1 minute. It seems like it's performing a literal subtraction (which is I guess what I'm telling it to do). Instead, how do I find the difference?

Note: It works when the first timestamp is "larger"/occurs later than the second. For reference, the results come from comparing values between two dictionaries, where the values are timestamps and the keys match.

```
comparison = {(dict1[x], dict2[x]): dict1[x] - dict2[x] for x in dict1 if x in dict2}
```

Comment: is there a reason you cannot do `comparison = {(dict2[x], dict1[x]): dict2[x] - dict1[x] for x in dict2 if x in dict1}`?

Comment: does `comparison = {(dict1[x], dict2[x]): max(dict1[x] - dict2[x], dict2[x] - dict1[x]) for x in dict1 if x in dict2}` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *is* the difference. The difference between the two datetimes you are subtracting is -1 days, 23 hours, and 59 minutes, a.k.a. -1 minutes.

If you want the absolute value of the difference, take the absolute value:

```
>>> x = datetime.timedelta(minutes=-1)
>>> x
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86340)
>>> abs(x)
datetime.timedelta(0, 60)
```

Comment: To clarify/elaborate, this is how `timedelta` stores information: number of days and number of seconds. It doesn't have a way to represent "negative" seconds, so the workaround is to have `-1` days and `86400 - 60` seconds to represent a change of minus one minute.

Comment: Absolute value won't return `-1 minutes` though, which seems to be what OP expects.

Comment: Awesome, had no idea you could take the absolute value of a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works if the first value is larger than the other then why not do something like:

```
def difference_between_dates(date1, date2):
    if date1 > date2:
        return date1 - date2
    else:
        return date2 - date1
```